# SQL Select id's from PHP serialised array

Tags: sql, regex, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to create a database view to act as a pivot table in a many to many relationship between `pages` and `posts`.

The data is stored by Wordpress Advanced custom fields as a serialised array:

`wp_postmeta` tabel:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key            | meta_value                                    |
+---------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| 155     | 47      | page_content_blocks | a:3:{i:0;s:2:"29";i:1;s:2:"42";i:2;s:2:"32";} |
+---------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

What the "pivot" view needs to look like:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | page_id | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 47      | 29      |
| 2  | 47      | 42      |
| 3  | 47      | 32      |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I have tried getting there with this:

```sql
select post_id as page_id,
       regexp_substr(meta_value, '(?<=i:[0-9];s:[0-9]:")([0-9]+)(?=";)') as post_id
from wp_postmeta
where meta_key = 'page_content_blocks';
```

But that gives me only a row for the first match. I have no idea how to loop through all matches and create a row for each.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working? I know it can easily be done in PHP but that is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From the table you provided above, number you required is the only value that surrounded with quote. Hence you can limit your look behind assertion till `:"`
Can you try,

```regex
regexp_substr(meta_value, '(?<=:")([0-9]+)(?=";)')
```

Comment: This does work and solves the problem in cases where the array is bigger than 9 items. Still with this query: `select post_id as page_id, regexp_substr(meta_value, '(?<=:")([0-9]+)(?=";)') as post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'page_content_blocks';` it only makes a row for the first match. I have no idea how to somehow loop through the matches

Comment: You can pass number occurrences to search for as a parameter in `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099)

Comment: I don't know the number of related posts before I get the regex matches. Isn't there a way to loop through them? Does `regexp_substr ` even get all matches or does it stop at the first if occurrences is not provided?

Comment: Default occurence is 1

Answer (score 0):

Which database & version are you using?

I use a piece of code (sorry i've lost te source) on MS SQL server using Common Table Expressions (CTE) inside an table valued function.

The problem is you need to loop trough the string (probably using the same regexp) and for each loop you need to save the iteration (i) and add 1 and add a record.

this is my code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split]
    (
        @String NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
        AS(
            SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
            UNION ALL
            SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
                FROM Split
                WHERE endpos > 0
        )
        SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
            'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
        FROM Split
    )
```